# list separator expected compile error when calling inStr

Tags: excel, vba

```
Public Function test232()
     test232 = inStr(String1:="hello", String2:=":")
End Function
```

I am getting the error: "Compile error: list separator expected" (my translation) when I try to insert this code in a module. The part of the code ":=" after String1 is selected after the error is pointed.
I searched for a solution online but coudn't find it.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Choose either `test232 = InStr("hello", ":")` or `test232 = VBA.InStr(Start:=1, String1:="hello", String2:=":")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inStr(String1:="hello", String2:=":")

should be

inStr("hello", ":")